# Potential of a charge placed in the middle of two other charges

Tags: electrostatics

Is the potential of two charges adds or subtract when you are going to find the potential at the middle?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It adds irrespective of the position of the point at which potential should be found as potential is a scalar quantity
So it should be $$V=\frac{k}{r}.(q_1+q_2)$$

We consider the negative sign when the charge itself is negative, as $-ve$ charges are considered to have an opposite potential to that of positive charges